# Use of idss data in Level-2 S-function

Tags: simulink

I am trying to write a level-2 S-function for use in system identification live during a simulation using the n4sid function. However, it does not appear that the output of the n4sid function, an idss datatype, is supported in the output. Is there a way to output this data type from an S-function? Alternatively, can this data type be used internally in an S-function and fed directly into another Matlab function inside the S-function code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to output this data type from an S-function?

No.

Alternatively, can this data type be used internally in an S-function and fed directly into another Matlab function inside the S-function code?

Yes.
You can create data/destroy data/call functions etc just like any other piece of MATLAB code.